# How to initialize read only memory locations in heap in C?

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char* c = malloc(1);
    *c = 'a';
    printf("%c\n",*c);
}
```

This code obviously throws the following compile error:

```
file1.c:7:3: error: assignment of read-only location ‘*c’
*c = 'a';
^
```

How do I initialize a const variable in heap memory?

Comment: Do this in two steps: `char *m = malloc(1); *m = 'a'; const char *c = m;` Then, pass around `c` to all your other functions [and never use `m` again except for an eventual `free(m)`]. You could also do `*(char *) c = 'a';` as an alternative. Caveat emptor as in each case you have to _know_ that `c` actually _does_ pointer to memory that you can change.

Comment: I don't think this is really what you're asking, but: some OSes do allow you to specify pages of memory as read-only. On POSIX or Linux, for example, you might call `mmap( NULL, BIG_SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, filedes, 0 );` to allocate read-only pages of memory initialized to the contents of some file.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, understand that there is no such thing as "read only locations in the heap".  The heap is 100% writable.  `malloc()` is defined as returning `void *`.  You are allowed to write to the data pointed to by the pointers which `malloc` returns.

But then the second thing to understand is that `const` doesn't necessarily mean "read only", either.

There *is* such a thing as read-only memory, and it will often be pointed to by `const` pointers, and if (despite any `const` pointer) you do manage to try to write to read-only memory, you will typically get an exception of some kind.

But you can have read-only memory that's pointed to by a non-`const` pointer, and you can have a `const` pointer that points to writable memory.

So what `const` really means is "I promise not to write to this memory" or "I declare my intent not to write to this memory", with the added stipulation that "I would like the compiler to give me compile-time errors if I accidentally try to write to this memory."

If you have an ordinary `const` pointer, you can initialize it, once.  You can say things like

```
const str1[] = "hello";
```

and

```
const *str2 = "world";
```

even though later attempts to update the strings like

```
*str1 = 'x';    /* WRONG */
```

or

```
*str2 = 'y';    /* WRONG */
```

would fail.  (You can think of this as the "initialization exception" for `const`-qualified data.

But as you've discovered, there's no such exception for a `const` pointer which you initialize by calling `malloc`.  If you want to get some memory from `malloc`, and initialize it once, and then promise not to modify it later, and if you want to get the compiler to enforce this promise for you, you can't do it directly, unless you use the two-pointer workaround described in the comments and in [klutt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072407/how-to-initialize-read-only-memory-locations-in-heap-in-c/51072502#51072502).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a read only location in the heap. See Steve Summits answer for a good explanation.

Whatever you do to achieve this, it will still be up to you to make sure that you don't write in those locations. You can protect yourself pretty well, but not 100%.

You could do something like this:

```
char * x = malloc(1);
*x = 'a';
const char * c = x;
// Promise to not use the pointer x again
printf("%c\n",*c);
```

Or if you prefer to encapsulate it a little bit:

```
const char * init()
{
    char* c = malloc(1);
    if(c == NULL) { // Always check if allocation is successful
        // Code for error handling
    }
    *c = 'a';
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    const char * p = init();
    printf("%c\n",*p);
}
```

Note that it is still allowed to write `char * p = init()` without `const` and this will indeed make it possible to write `*p = 'a'`, but you will at least trigger this warning:

```
warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target 
type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
     char * p = init();
```

Another thing to be aware of here is that you will get a warning if you call `free(p)`, because `p` is a `const` pointer. If you declare `p` as just a `char *` you will get rid of this warning, but you will instead get the warning I mentioned in the previous paragraph. (And, of course you will also lose all write protection you were trying to get by declaring it as a const)

To get around this, you can free the memory with `free((char*)p)`

As a side note, if you want to make sure that you never change where `p` is pointing, then you can declare it like this `const char * const p = init()`. That will make it impossible to make `p` point to something else later in the code.

Comment: Might as well show how to free the memory as `free(p);` will complain.

Comment: The second example with the encapsulation is inadvisable, as the `const char*` cannot be passed to `free()` (without a cast, which in this case happens to be safe). Would also suggest the pointers have type `char * const` and `const char * const`, to prevent accidental reassignment of them, and a check for `NULL`, just on principle.

Comment: Well, I cannot assume that the user does not want to point the pointer to something else, but I can write something about it. I'll add a NULL check too.